# Можно ли подключить субдомен к файлу а не к директории

Tags: домен, поддомены, vds

Ну вопрос уже написан в теме, добавлю лишь от себя:
сайт на vds и субдомен для мобильной версии, чтобы обращение было в той же директории что и основной домен, но лишь к отдельному файлу. 
Можно ли такое сделать? 
Это можно конечно узнать путем эксперимента на сервере, но у меня нет лишнего, лишь основной, так что решил задать вопрос. 
Спасибо за ответ.

---

Пример:
**domen.com - /www/index.php**
**m.domen.com - /www/index_m.php**

Comment: В конфигурации web сервера указываете для субдомена ту же папку, что и для основного (например делая его алиасом) и пишите правило перезаписи (rewrite)

Comment: Что-то не понял. Можно пример в виде кода для конфигов?

Comment: https://www.komtet.ru/lib/etc/ispconfig/ispconfig-3/pereadresaciya-poddomena-s-pomoschyu-apache-mod-rewrite-pri-sohranenii-url-adresa  как то так, только в правой части правила не директория а просто /index_m.php ну и решать что с параметрами делать. И вы бы в вопросе указали какой веб сервер, они же все по разному конфигурятся

Comment: Это делается через .htaccess? Я думал через host файл.

Comment: host точно не причем. он отвечает за преобразование имен в ip, причем только для локальной машины. Вы всеравно субдомен у себя в DNS пропишите с тем же ip, что то же самое, что host только для всех. А то что вы просите - настройки именно web сервера. Хоть .htaccess, хоть конфиги web-сервера. Кстати, если в конфигах, то вы можете там явно описать для этого субдомена раздел, полную копию раздела основного сайта, только указать IndexFile index_m.php и даже rewrite не понадобится

Comment: В общем вот так можно написать? Или это не сработает?<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin m@domen.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/index_m.php"
    ServerName m.domen.com
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Ну да, как то так. посмотрел, в апаче опция выглядит "DirectoryIndex index_m.php"

Comment: Ну да, как то так. посмотрел, в апаче опция выглядит "DirectoryIndex index_m.php". Но она работает разумеется только если в передаваемом из браузера URL явно не содержится указание файла, который должен открыться.